# Running dotnet run does not start website

Tags: .net-core

I ran my website using `dotnet run` and it worked. Then I did ctrl-c and it stopped. Then I did `dotnet run` again and the cursor went to the next line and nothing else happend. The web browser hangs too.

How do I make my website start again?

Comment: What OS are you running, and do you also run VIsual Studio? I have ideas, but don't want to answer without more detail.

Comment: I have Code but I fancied running it in Terminal on MacOS.

Comment: Ok my idea might apply (sort of). Try killing all processes associated with dotnet, VS code, Microsoft, msbuild, etc. Sometimes these keep file handles open, and so on...

Comment: Right, well that worked. I killed all the dotnet processes and now it works. So I guess ctrl-C doesn't do what it says it does on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like this I tend to nuke everything related to `dotnet`, VS, VS code, Microsoft (no offense gang), JetBrains (same), and MSBuild.

For Windows create a batch or shell script with the commands below. You might want to tweak it; add or remove commands as needed.

For MacOS you can translate this script to native or use Activity Monitor.

> Use at your own risk!

```
taskkill /F /IM MSBuild*
taskkill /F /IM ServiceHost*
taskkill /F /IM dotnet.exe
taskkill /F /IM vs*.exe
taskkill /F /IM ServiceHub*
taskkill /F /IM Microsoft.*
taskkill /F /IM JetBrains.*
taskkill /F /IM devenv.*
taskkill /F /IM BESClient.*
```

The reason this often works is that many of these tools keep hold of resources, especially file handles, longer than they should.

Comment: ctrl-c actually reports the number of processes it's killed. Apparently doesn't get them all.